webapp works fine on windows, on ubuntu droplet I get this error: express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option,
Using an Ubuntu droplet from DigitalOcean, When I try executing the index.js file that starts the server, I get this message: "express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option server/index.js:20:2"
I built this application on Windows and works just fine but on Ubuntu, I'm getting this message.
I have .env installed and have my SESSION_SECRET configured on that file but still getting that message and my server won't even load.
I tried putting the session secret key into the js file directly but that does not work either and also defeats the purpose of a secret. also tried exporting an object as a session secret but that gave me errors. (index.js:20:2 is secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET)
const express = require("express");
const { pool } = require("../config/dbConfig");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const passport = require("passport");
const initializePassport = require("../config/passportConfig");

if (process.env !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").config();
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const app = express();

initializePassport(passport);

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
    })
);

